Override a base member function with different return type in the derived class
I have created a templated BinaryTree class to use for cases where I need binary trees (ASTs, decision, etc.). The idea was to put most of the tree behavior in the base class and have very slim (for basic tree behavior) derived classes that can focus on implementing other needed specialized behavior (AST, decision, etc).
This is the attempted code:
template< class T > class Base
{
private:
    T value{};
    Base* left, * right;
public:
    Base() : left{ nullptr }, right{ nullptr } {};
    Base(T val) : value{ val }, left{ nullptr }, right{ nullptr } {};
    Base* GetRightLeaf() const{ return right; }
    void SetRightLeaf(Base* node) { right = node; }
};

class DeriveBase :public Base<int>
{
public:
    DeriveBase():Base(){}
    DeriveBase(int val):Base(val){}
};

int main()
{
    DeriveBase b1(1), b2(2), b3(3);
    b2.SetRightLeaf(&b1);
    DeriveBase* c = b2.GetRightLeaf(); //right here we get compiler error
}

The error is:

a value of type "Base<int>" cannot be used to initialize an entity of type "DeriveBase"

Now, I understand these are two different types and that's why I get the error. My question is, how can I make this work?
Sure, you can say take the setter and getter out of the base class and implement them in the derived class. However, as I have mentioned above, I want as much of the specific "general" tree behavior as possible to be in the base class so that I can have "skinny" derived classes that can use as much functionality as possible from the base class.
Is this even possible?

You may be looking for CRTP.  Something like template<typename T, typename Derived> class Base { Derived* left, *right; }; (adjust other members accordingly). class DeriveBase :public Base<int, DeriveBase> ...

How do you create a tree if nodes have different types, like Base<int> and Base`?

What you are looking for is "covariant return types", just do a bit of research on that topic and you'll find enough info, explanations and examples. Oh, and yes, the way to implement it is "CRTP", another keyword for research.

You can replace CRTP with "deducing this" (aka Explicit Object Parameter) in C++23.

Try this:
template< class T > class Base
{
private:
    T value{};
    Base* left, * right;
public:
    Base() : left{ nullptr }, right{ nullptr } {};
    Base(T val) : value{ val }, left{ nullptr }, right{ nullptr } {};
    virtual ~Base() = default; // declare a virtual method to use polymorphism
    Base* GetRightLeaf() const{ return right; }
    void SetRightLeaf(Base* node) { right = node; }
};
class DeriveBase :public Base<int>
{
public:
    DeriveBase():Base(){}
    DeriveBase(int val):Base(val){}
};

int main()
{
    DeriveBase b1(1), b2(2), b3(3);
    b2.SetRightLeaf(&b1);
    // you must use dynamic_cast to convert Base<int>* to DeriveBase*
    Base<int>* c = b2.GetRightLeaf(); // good
    // DeriveBase* c = b2.GetRightLeaf(); // wrong
    DeriveBase* d = dynamic_cast<DeriveBase*>(c); // good
    return 0;
}

You need polymorphism to realize what you want: polymorphism

Note that in Base that Base * and Base * are the same, that there is no actual need to specify  within Base itself.

Even though it "works", dynamic_cast is rarely a good solution. For this particular problem it might have scalability issues. CRTP mentioned in the comments seems way better.
